# peewee: importing a model into another model throws TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, peewee

Basically i have my models like this structure:

```
\models
\\__init__.py
\\helpers.py
\\modelA.py
\\modelB.py
```

my model A contains:

```
from helpers import BaseModel
import modelB
class modelA(BaseModel):
    #something...
    def get_all_modelB(self):
        return modelB.select().where(modelB.id == self.id)
```

my model B contains:

```
from helpers import BaseModel
import modelA
from peewee import ForeingKeyField
class modelB(BaseModel):
    #something
    modelA_id = ForeingKeyField(modelA, related_name='something')
```

but then when i try to use this it shows

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 1246, in __init__
issubclass(rel_model, Model):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

which is weird for me because apparently im importing only the file as a module so i tried this:

my new model A contains:

```
from helpers import BaseModel
from modelB import modelB
class modelA(BaseModel):
    #something...
    def get_all_modelB(self):
        return modelB.select().where(modelB.id == self.id)
```

my new model B contains:

```
from helpers import BaseModel
from modelA import modelA
from peewee import ForeingKeyField
class modelB(BaseModel):
    #something
    modelA_id = ForeingKeyField(modelA, related_name='something')


File "C:\some\random\path\modelB.py", some line, in <module>
  from modelA import modelA
ImportError: cannot import name modelA
```

what am i doing wrong? is there another way to do this in a easier way or ina correct way?

thanks

Comment: You have circular imports:  `modelB` imports `modelA`, and `modelA` imports `modelB`.  Don't do that.

Comment: thanks, i changed the function get_all_modelB from modelA to get_modelsA_from_modelB to modelA and it worked